# Extracting data from an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which shows these values.

```
turn-right
Go straight
turn-left
```

How do i get the 2nd value Go straight only ? I have this following codes.

```
var text = $('#personDataTable tr:first td:first').text();
```

This code above allows me to get the very first 'turn-right'. I tried to use

```
var text = $('#personDataTable tr:second td:first').text();
```

but it does not work.

This is the code i use to draw the table.

```
function drawTable(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
    drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]);
  }
}

function drawRow(steps) {
  var row = $("<tr />")
  $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
  row.append($("<td>" + steps.maneuver + "</td>"));
  console.log('Added Table');
}
```

This is my html

```
<table id="personDataTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Maneuver</th>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `:second` is not a valid CSS selector. Try `:nth-child(2)`. But that does rely on there not being any empty text nodes between the rows so that the second row is also the second child node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr:second` is invalid CSS. The correct syntax is :

```
'#personDataTable tr:nth-child(2) td:first'
```